# TypeScript compiler confused with large inheritance/extension chain

Tags: generics, typescript, interface, tsc

I have the following (reasonably complex) extension chain. It is a minimal reproducible example of my problem (obviously the classes will have behavioural implementations in my application).

```
export class BaseModel
{
    public someBaseModelMethod(): void { }
}

export class BaseView
{
    public someBaseViewMethod(): void { }
}

export class CollectionView<TChildView extends BaseView, TModel extends BaseModel>
    extends BaseView
{
    public someCollectionViewMethod(): void { }
}

export class ItemView<TModel extends BaseModel>
    extends BaseView
{
    public setItem(model: TModel): void { }
}

export interface IGridView<TChildView extends ItemView<TModel>, TModel extends BaseModel>
    extends CollectionView<TChildView, TModel>
{
    someGridViewMethod(): void;
}

export class GridView<TChildView extends ItemView<TModel>, TModel extends BaseModel>
    extends CollectionView<TChildView, TModel>
    implements IGridView<TChildView, TModel>
{
    public someGridViewMethod(): void { }
}

function bind<TInterface>(key: string, implementation: new (...args: any[]) => TInterface) {
    // do some bindings here
}

bind<IGridView<ItemView<BaseModel>, BaseModel>>("IGridView", GridView);
```

When I compile, I get an error on the `GridView` part of the final line (the `bind` statement). The error is as follows:

```
TS2345 Argument of type 'typeof GridView' is not assignable to parameter of type 'new (...args: any[]) => IGridView<ItemView<BaseModel>, BaseModel>'.
    Type 'CollectionView<any, any>' is not assignable to type 'IGridView<ItemView<BaseModel>, BaseModel>'.
        Property 'someGridViewMethod' is missing in type 'CollectionView<any, any>'.
```

As you can see, it is expecting `someGridViewMethod` to be on `CollectionView`. However, `GridView` **extends** `CollectionView`, so why is it expecting to find `GridView` methods on the `CollectionView` class?

---

The code compiles correctly in `2.0.3`, but not in `1.8.10`.

Comment: This code, when copied to playground, produces no errors

Comment: Sorry @NitzanTomer, I have updated my question - it compiles correctly in `2.0.3` but not in `1.8.10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This compiles fine in both `1.8.x` and `2.x`:

```
type TypedGridView = { new (...args: any[]): IGridView<ItemView<BaseModel>, BaseModel> };

function bind<TInterface>(key: string, implementation: new (...args: any[]) => TInterface) {
    // do some bindings here
}

bind("IGridView", GridView as TypedGridView);
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=export%20class%20BaseModel%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20public%20someBaseModelMethod()%3A%20void%20%7B%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aexport%20class%20BaseView%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20public%20someBaseViewMethod()%3A%20void%20%7B%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aexport%20class%20CollectionView%3CTChildView%20extends%20BaseView%2C%20TModel%20extends%20BaseModel%3E%20extends%20BaseView%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20public%20someCollectionViewMethod()%3A%20void%20%7B%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aexport%20class%20ItemView%3CTModel%20extends%20BaseModel%3E%20extends%20BaseView%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20public%20setItem(model%3A%20TModel)%3A%20void%20%7B%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aexport%20interface%20IGridView%3CTChildView%20extends%20ItemView%3CTModel%3E%2C%20TModel%20extends%20BaseModel%3E%0A%20%20%20%20extends%20CollectionView%3CTChildView%2C%20TModel%3E%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20someGridViewMethod()%3A%20void%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aexport%20class%20GridView%3CTChildView%20extends%20ItemView%3CTModel%3E%2C%20TModel%20extends%20BaseModel%3E%0A%20%20%20%20extends%20CollectionView%3CTChildView%2C%20TModel%3E%0A%20%20%20%20implements%20IGridView%3CTChildView%2C%20TModel%3E%0A%7B%0A%20%20%20%20public%20someGridViewMethod()%3A%20void%20%7B%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Atype%20TypedGridView%20%3D%20%7B%20new%20(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%3A%20IGridView%3CItemView%3CBaseModel%3E%2C%20BaseModel%3E%20%7D%3B%0A%0Afunction%20bind%3CTInterface%3E(key%3A%20string%2C%20implementation%3A%20new%20(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20TInterface)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20do%20some%20bindings%20here%0A%7D%0A%0Abind(%22IGridView%22%2C%20GridView%20as%20TypedGridView)%3B))

It seems that the `1.8.x` compiler fails to recognize `GridView` as a constructor to:

```
IGridView<ItemView<BaseModel>, BaseModel>
```